# matlab: expand vector using colon notation

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I would like to expand an existing vector into a matrix using colon notation, or some other efficient way.

For example, using colon notation to create a matrix, I can do

```
< [0:4;5:9]
```

which will give me

```
< [
0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9]
```

I want to be able to do the same thing but with a provided original vector and range. For example, if my original vector is [1;3] and my range is 1 around the existing values, I wish to obtain the following output:

```
< [
0 1 2
2 3 4]
```

I know I can do this using a loop but I was wondering if there's a way I can do without the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want; change `vec` and `range` appropriately:

```
vec = [1; 3]
range = 1
repmat(vec, 1, range * 2 + 1) + repmat([-range:range], size(vec))
```

Comment: Yep that does it. Thanks so much! I didn't even know what `kron` was. I know that you can use `repmat` to expand a matrix but I'm not sure if that's applicable here.

Comment: @Myx: I changed it to use `repmat`; I remembered that you could do it with `kron` but the Octave manual says to use `repmat` instead.